# Not delete specified content from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row, corresponding-records

I've recently made a PHP, that should; if click a link delete a certain row within one of my MYSQL tables.

The script below has everything but the link `[href=delete_ac.php?id etc...]` leads to the page but when the page activates it echo `ERROR` instead of deleting the row.

```
<h1>Members</h1> 
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th>ID</th> 
        <th>Username</th> 
        <th>E-Mail Address</th> 
        <th></th>
    </tr> 
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
            <td><a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">delete</a></td> 
        </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
</table>
```

`delete_ac.php`
The script below is what should delete it but it isn't

```
<?php

    require("../php/bp-connectionAdmin.php");

    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $query = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

   if ($result) {
        echo "Successful";
   } else {
        echo "ERROR";
   }
?>
```

Comment: echo out `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query` and see what the error is. Also you should sanitize your input variables before adding them to queries.

Comment: You can use `mysql_error()` to get the *actual* error from the database, which should give information about what the problem is.  Also, *please* stop using the `mysql_*` data access library.  *At least* upgrade to `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.  Use these libraries to create prepared statements instead of opening the SQL injection vulnerability that you currently have in your code.

Comment: Also the reason why you should stop using mysql_* functions is that they are depracted and will be removed in future

Comment: Check in `../php/bp-connectionAdmin.php` where you make a connection, that you selected proper database by `mysql_select_db()` because you used only table name in your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the ID numeric only? Would the addition of quote marks around $id not help?

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$id'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Not sure...but give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Put on the line after $query = "DELETE ..

An

```
echo "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id";
die;
```

Then you will see what goes wrong.
Personally i would remove the ', assuming that the id=integer, and you will have:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=$id";
```

If not, try that echood query directly in your Database window and you will see what is wrong.

Most probably you should change your line into

```
 $id=intval($_GET['id']);
```

which is also much more secure!